# Creating a SQL table, passing a tableName as parameter using C# gives an error

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure `createNewTable` which creates a new table.

If I execute the procedure as it is without C#, it works where I have hardcoded the name of the table which is `testTable5` (the code which is commented).

What I am trying to do now, is to execute this stored procedure using C#. What I also want to do here is to pass a name for the table as a parameter. So I try to pass the name: `testTable5`.

But I get this error when I execute the C# code:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'testTable5'

I wonder what I could be doing wrong in this code?

Stored procedure (commented out code is the original code that works as hardcoded)

```
--CREATE PROCEDURE createNewTable
--AS
--CREATE TABLE testTable5
--(
--    [DateTime]    SMALLDATETIME  NOT NULL,
--    [FeatureNbr]  SMALLINT         NOT NULL,
--    [Value]       FLOAT (53)       NULL,
--    [Bool]        BIT              NULL,
--  CONSTRAINT UC_testTable5 UNIQUE (DateTime),
--  CONSTRAINT PK_testTable5 PRIMARY KEY (FeatureNbr, DateTime)
--);


CREATE PROCEDURE createNewTable
    @tableName nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FullQuery nvarchar(1000)
    SET @FullQuery = N'CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' ([DateTime] SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL, [FeatureNbr] SMALLINT NOT NULL, [Value] FLOAT (53) NULL, [Bool] BIT NULL, 
                     CONSTRAINT UC_' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' UNIQUE (DateTime), 
                     CONSTRAINT PK_' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' PRIMARY KEY (FeatureNbr, DateTime));'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @FullQuery;
END
```

C# code (which executes this stored procedure)

```
void createNewTable()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("createNewTable", conn); //1. create a command object identifying the stored procedure
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; //2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tableName", "testTable5"));

        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

static private string GetConnectionString()
{
    return "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\andre\\source\\repos\\TestDatabaseCreation\\DatabaseTest.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UC_' + QUOTENAME(@tableName)` would create something like `UC_[TableName]`. Object names cannot contain special characters unless that are delimit identified (so if you *really* wanted a unique constraint with that name you would define it as `[UC_[tablename]]]`; but I **strongly** suggest against any such name).

You need to quote the entire value: `QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'UC_',@tablename))`. That would produce the value `[UC_tablename]`.

Also, the parameter `@tableName` should *not* be an `nvarchar(MAX)`. An object's name cannot be longer than 128 characters, and there is a specific data type for object names, `sysname`, which is a synonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`.

Comment: then I understand. I have to `QUOTENAME` everything there. This worked now when I did it that way. That was good to know. Then, it should be okay to declare it like this: `@tableName nvarchar(128)` ? (This worked)

Comment: I personally suggest using `sysname` over `nvarchar(128)`, as it is the specific data type designed for object names, @coding .

Comment: A side question. I am not sure if it is okay to ask like this. But how can one return that the table was created successfully. This command: `int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); if (i != 0) { MessageBox.Show(i + "Table Created"); }` shows: `-1Table Created`. Shouldn´t it be: `1Table Created` ?

Comment: Yes I see, I will use `sysname` instead for object names. This is good to know.

Comment: My C# knowledge is limited at best, @coding . If you want to understand that thenpost a new question in regards to that; as it's a completely different problem to what yuo have asked about here.

Comment: @coding, the proc with throw an error if not created successfully so a simple try/catch in the c# code is enough. Although you could return a value from the proc (return code, scalar resultset, or output parameter), doing so is just extra code without value, IMHO.

Comment: @Dan, I understand. I might then add a `try/catch` block and catch and handle the error that way. I will try with that also.